# PIC12F629 memory overflow

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip, mplab

I am new to PIC microcontroller programming. I am trying to programming PIC12F629. I have a hex file (size 518bytes). When I am trying to write using PICkit2, it shows memory overflow. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    TRISIO=0b00000111;
   // ANSEL=0b00000000;
    GPIObits.GP0=0;
    GPIObits.GP1=0;
    GPIObits.GP2=0;
    int count;
    while(1)
    {
        jmp1:
        if(GP4==1)
        {
            goto jmp1;
        }
        else
        {
            jmp2 :
            GP1=1;
            __delay_ms(10000);
            GP0=1;
            count=0;
            jmp3:
            if(GP5==1)
            {
                count=0;
                GP2=1;
                __delay_ms(40000);
                goto jmp5;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                __delay_ms(5000);
                if(count==60)
                {
                    GP1=0;
                    goto jmp5;

                }
                else
                {
                    goto jmp3;
                }
            }
            jmp5:
            GP0=0;
            GP2=0;
            jmp4:
            if(GP3==1)
            {
                goto jmp2;
            }
            else
            {
                if(GP4==1)
                {
                    goto jmp1;
                }
                else
                {
                    goto jmp4;
                }
            }
        }
    }

   return 0; 
}
```

Flowchart of intended behaviour:

[image: flowchart]

Comment: Can you edit your question? Add all code inside the code brackets, its barely readable this way. What is the purpose of this code? What have you tried already?

Comment: i have put all code inside the code brackets. i have 4 loops and one timers for 5 minutes. i don't know the timers programming or how to do it. so i use delay_ms repeatedly. plz help me.

Comment: Did you create the .hex file by compiling (building) your source for the 12F629 target? Could you provide that .hex file? Does the pickit2 recognize the 12F629?

Comment: yes i have the .hex file. and pickit2 recognize it. how to provide it @WoutervanOoijen

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: You have `goto` targets inside `if..else` constructs, which I've no idea how the compiler will try to handle. Can you tidy this up and avoid the `goto`'s?

Comment: Apart from the problem you're having with memory, the code is also wrong because your `TRIS` bits don't reflect the port usage - you are reading from outputs and writing to inputs.

Comment: @RogerRowland thanks. i have forgotten to change TRIS bois. i used goto statement in dev c++ compiler. i did not face any issue. what should i use in the place of goto statement?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7rlUXKVOcwCNkZUc1JXZlBrSTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The fact that it compiles ok doesn't mean it's good code. Can you describe in words what your program is supposed to do? If so, I will try to write a version without goto's, which might be a better starting point for you.

Comment: @RogerRowland i have flow chart. will it be ok? pic12f629 does not have any analog port. so ANSEL command would not work?

Comment: Yes, edit it in to your question if you can or post a link to an image.

Comment: @RogerRowland flow chart https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7rlUXKVOcwCZXkyVEx4Vi1QMlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, give me a while and I'll see what I can do ....

Comment: @RogerRowland thanx again in advance

Comment: "When I am **trying to write using PICkit2**, it shows memory overflow." - I tried programming your hex file into a 12F675 with my PICkit2 - worked perfectly!

Comment: @BruceAbbott thanks. my program is now working. don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, following on from comments, here's a bit of code that compiles ok, roughly follows what I understand from your flowchart, and which doesn't use any `goto`'s.

You will need to verify the logic, calculate and insert the correct configuration for the timer, and make any other changes that have been caused by my misunderstanding of the logic.

You can see that `goto` only serves to make the flow more difficult to understand. So, start from something that's more like my code than yours and I think your "memory problem" will go away. I suspect the compiler is/was trying to do something clever with the `goto` logic and ended up with some recursive implementation or something like that.

Here's my code - note that this is only an example!!

```
void main()
{
    // assumptions:
    //    I/P1 is GP4
    //    I/P2 is GP5
    //    I/P3 is GP3
    //    O/P1 is GP1
    //    O/P2 is GP0
    //    O/P3 is GP2

    // set inputs/outputs
    TRISIO = 0b111000;

    // reset O/P1, O/P2 and O/P3
    GP1 = 0;
    GP0 = 0;
    GP2 = 0;

    // main loop
    while (1)
    {
        // wait until I/P1 is low
        while (GP4 == 1);

        // set O/P1 and O/P2 with delay
        GP1 = 1;            // O/P1
        __delay_ms(10000L);
        GP0 = 1;            // O/P2

        // start 5 minute timer
        // NB - you need to set the registers according to your clock speed etc.
        // I'm not going to do the whole thing for you, but this is the idea:
        OPTION_REGbits.T0CS = 0;
        OPTION_REGbits.PSA = 0;
        OPTION_REGbits.PS = 0b111;  // you choose the correct prescaler value
        TMR0 = 0;                   // zeroise the timer

        // wait until timer expires or I/P2 goes high
        // NB - the 9999 value is what you need to calculate
        // to get a 5 min timeout with your clock and prescaler
        // it may be necessary to do this differently if your
        // clock is too fast, so maybe a loop with a counter
        while (TMR0 < 99999 && GP5 == 0);

        // check what just happened ...
        if (GP5 == 1)
        {
            // IP/2 went high, set O/P3
            GP2 = 1;
            __delay_ms(40000L);
        }

        // in all cases, reset O/P1, O/P2 and O/P3
        GP1 = 0;
        GP0 = 0;
        GP2 = 0;

        // the bottom two decision boxes in your flowchart don't
        // make sense, but I have assumed some logic and coded below
        // so you can see the general way to avoid goto's

        // wait until I/P3 or I/P1 goes high
        while (GP3 == 0 || GP4 == 0);
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks. tmro register is 8 bit. so it will contain maximum 255.

Comment: @Sonu, yes I know, that's why I used an invalid number in my example and made that comment.